# Installing Replication on SQL 2005 SP3

Tags: sql-server-2005, replication

I think I screwed myself on the setup of SQL 2005.  I installed Database Services, but forgot to install replication.  I then installed SP3.  Is it possible to install replication after sp3?  Or do I need to start from scratch?

Answer (score 1):

You can install replication and then install SP3 again, which will only update the newly installed components. There's no need to start from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

I tried that.  It was erroring out telling me the default instance already exists.  It's only letting me do it if I create a new instance, which isn't what I want.

Comment: You're selecting to add features to an existing installation and only selecting features that have not previously been installed (replication)?

Comment: Correct.  Except replication is part of the core database service.  The only way to install it after the fact through the installer it seems is to install a second instance.